# Store all guessed letters in hangman game

Tags: php, mysql

im writting a hangman game using php and my sql. Im almost done, there are some final issues when i try to store all the guessed letters and then echo them. The following code shows only the two latest guesses in the game, not all(maximum 5 guesses). Can someone help me with this?

The numFailed Guess variable works correct, showing all the guesses, but when i try to echo those guesses only the latest appears.

Im thinking about an array solution, any ideas?

Here is my code...

```
    //if word is incorrect 
    if($correct!=1){
    $numFailedGuess++;
    $_SESSION['numFailedGuess']= $numFailedGuess;


    //entry to fail guesses
    if(!isset($S_SESSION['incorrectGuesses'])){
        $_SESSION['incorrectGuesses']="";
    }

    $_SESSION['incorrectGuesses'].=$alpha. ", ";



    $incorrectGuesses=$incorrectGuesses.$_SESSION['incorrectGuesses'];


    }else{...
```

Comment: Is there another place in the code where `$_SESSION['incorrectGuesses']` gets assigned?

Comment: $S_SESSION['incorrectGuesses'] should be $_SESSION, I suspect you are always setting your session to blank because this never set (because it doesn't actually exist)

Comment: I realise that is in about 4 places, I mean specifically !isset($S_SESSION['incorrectGuesses']

Comment: yes, in the variable setup and in reset function, for a new game...

Comment: The typo in your code really shouldn't be there. Stackoverflow isn't meant to be an IDE replacement.

Answer (score 1):

```
//entry to fail guesses
if(!isset($S_SESSION['incorrectGuesses'])){
    $_SESSION['incorrectGuesses']="";
}
```

this is incorrect it should be `$_SESSION`. you have a typo which is causing you to always reset your session to blank, because `$S_SESSION` does not exist

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to call the [session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) function, so you can start using the $_SESSION global variable. After that you could store the values in an array and after you work with it you store it on the session.
I am assuming you are using $_POST to get the values from the user.

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['incorrectGuesses']))
   $arrayGuess = [];
else
   $arrayGuess = $_SESSION['incorrectGuesses'];
if(isset($_POST['guess']))
{
   array_push($arrayGuess, $_POST['guess']);
}
$_SESSION['incorrectGuesses'] = $arrayGuess;
print_r($arrayGuess);
```

Comment: why wouldn't you just declare the session if it wasn't set and the add the data in, what's the benefit of creating an extra array?

Comment: Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array, it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.  from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php